Pandas. Сводная таблица со значениями одновременно по текстовым и числовым полям
Всем привет!
Прошу помощи. Имею такой датафрейм:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sku_sellout': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'],
    'labels': ['менее 100%', '100-200%', 'более 200%', 'более 200%', 'менее 100%'],
    'price': [100, 200, 300, 1000, 100],
    'ranges': ['0-100', '100-200', '200-300', '900-1000', '0-100'],
    'rur_extr': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
    'qnt_extr': [10, 20, 30, 40, 15]
})




sku_sellout
labels
price
ranges
rur_extr
qnt_extr




a
менее 100%
100
0-100
1
10


a
100-200%
200
100-200
2
20


b
более 200%
300
200-300
3
30


c
более 200%
1000
900-1000
4
40


a
менее 100%
100
0-100
1
15



Из него мне необходимо получить вот такой:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'sku_sellout': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    'metrics':['ranges', 'rur_extr','qnt_extr','ranges', 'rur_extr','qnt_extr','ranges', 'rur_extr','qnt_extr'],
    'менее 100%': ['0-100',2,25,None,None,None,None,None,None],
    '100-200%': ['100-200%',2,20,None,None,None,None,None,None],
    'более 200%': [None,None,None,'200-300',3,30,'900-1000',4,40]
})




sku_sellout
metrics
менее 100%
100-200%
более 200%




a
ranges
0-100
100-200%
None


a
rur_extr
2
2
None


a
qnt_extr
25
20
None


b
ranges
None
None
200-300


b
rur_extr
None
None
3


b
qnt_extr
None
None
30


c
ranges
None
None
900-1000


c
rur_extr
None
None
4


c
qnt_extr
None
None
40



Т.е. суть следующая - в строках иметь измерение sku_sellout и metrics (ranges, rur_extr, qnt_extr), а в столбцах значения labels.
На пересечении иметь:

если это rur_extr или qnt_extr, то сумму соответствующего поля.
если это ranges, то первое попавшееся значение (aggfunc='first') по этому sku_sellout и label - оно всегда будет одинаковым.

Делал через melt с последующим pivot_table, но не получилось применить условную логику к столбцу: применять то 'first', то 'sum'.

Кажется, что проще будет разделить на две сводные и далее их объединить
# Разворачиваем
temp = df.melt(
    id_vars=['sku_sellout', 'labels'],
    value_vars=['ranges', 'rur_extr', 'qnt_extr'],
    var_name='metrics')

# Сводная для суммируемых столбцов
extr = temp[
    temp['metrics'].isin(['rur_extr', 'qnt_extr'])].pivot_table(
    index=['sku_sellout', 'metrics'],
    columns='labels',
    values='value',
    aggfunc='sum')

# Сводная для столбцов с первым значением
ranges = temp[
    temp['metrics'] == 'ranges'].pivot_table(
    index=['sku_sellout', 'metrics'],
    columns='labels',
    values='value',
    aggfunc='first')

# Соединяем и преобразовываем
final_df = (pd.concat([extr, ranges])
            .sort_values(by=['sku_sellout', 'metrics'])
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
            )[['sku_sellout', 'metrics', 'менее 100%', '100-200%', 'более 200%']]

Вывод:
print(final_df)

  sku_sellout   metrics менее 100% 100-200% более 200%
0           a  qnt_extr       25.0     20.0        NaN
1           a    ranges      0-100  100-200        NaN
2           a  rur_extr        2.0      2.0        NaN
3           b  qnt_extr        NaN      NaN       30.0
4           b    ranges        NaN      NaN    200-300
5           b  rur_extr        NaN      NaN        3.0
6           c  qnt_extr        NaN      NaN       40.0
7           c    ranges        NaN      NaN   900-1000
8           c  rur_extr        NaN      NaN        4.0

